# Error :'+' cannot add two pointers

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Got error " '+' cannot add two pointers".

Can anyone explain me what's exactly wrong / how to solve it?

Information :movedb got table user which contain User_ID (integer) and password (text) . Line that now generates error , earlier returned false , so I thought that User_ID cannot be compared into username because of types (Qstring and integer) and made conversion.

login.cpp

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"

Login::Login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setDatabaseName("movedb");
    if(!db.open())
    {
        ui->Status->setText("Status: Failed to connect with database");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->Status->setText("Status: Ready to LogIn");
    }
}

Login::~Login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Login::on_Login_2_clicked()
{
    int username;
    QString password;
    username=ui->lineEdit_Username->text().toInt();
    password=ui->lineEdit_Password->text();
    if(!db.isOpen())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Failed to open database";
        return;
    }
    QSqlQuery qry;
    if(qry.exec("select * from user where User_ID='"+username+"' AND password'"+password+"'"))
    {
        int count=0;
        while(qry.next())
        {
           count++;
        }
        if(count==1)
        {
            ui->Login_status->setText("You have logged in");
        }
        if(count>1)
        {
            ui->Login_status->setText("Something went wrong - please contact with admin");
        }
        if(count<1)
        {
            ui->Login_status->setText("Failed to LogIn");
        }
    }


    else
    {
        ui->label->setText("Something is very Wrong ");
    }
}
```

-line that generates error:

```
 if(qry.exec("select * from user where User_ID='"+username+"' AND password'"+password+"'"))
```

Comment: owning raw pointers? There are smartpointers or simple member variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `char*`, `int`, `char*` and `QString`. Also, `=` in the query is missing, and number shouldn't be in quotes. It should be:

```
if(qry.exec("select * from user where
    User_ID="+QString::number(username)+" AND password='"+password+"'"))
```

But better idea is to prepare your queries to avoid this situation:

```
qry.prepare("select * from user where User_ID=:userid AND password=':password'");
qry.bindValue(":userid",username);
qry.bindValue(":password",password);
qry.exec();
```